# AWS Route 53, Private Link Endpoints and Private DNS with custom DNS names

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc, aws-private-link

I'm example.com and I consume a SaaS product from acme.com over private link.

They have accepted my endpoint connection request, I have enabled private DNS, and I can access the product using the endpoint DNS names.

We have also requested a custom DNS name for the endpoints - sausages.acme.com - which I can see in the management console alongside the internal AWS DNS entries for the endpoints.

Servers in my example.com VPC are unable to resolve sausages.acme.com to the endpoint IP.

Should this be happening natively and the provider has missed a step, or do I need to configured Route 53 to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to resolve DNS because you can't reach the hosted zone acme.com.

1. Considering acme.com is a private hosted zone, if so associate your vpc with that hosted zone. If it is not allowed then create your own private hosted zone with name acme.com and associate it with your vpc. Add route53 record sausage.acme.com to point endpoint DNS.
2. Add it in host file to enable local resolution